# Can't understand, why i can't take the returning object from function

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel

Here the code:

```
async function throwDice(msg) {
try {
    let a;
    a = await readData(msg)
    if (a == 'Error') {
        //return b
    }
    let text = ''
    if (data[msg.from.id] === undefined) {
        let replyMarkup = bot.keyboard([
            [' New game', ' Commands list']
        ], { resize: true });
        return msg.reply.text('⛔️ Critical Error ⛔️', { replyMarkup });
    } else {
        if (data[msg.from.id].canThrowDice) {
            let replyMarkup = bot.keyboard([
                [' Throw dice', ' Commands list']
            ], { resize: true });

            text = playerMove(msg, text)
            if (data[msg.from.id].leftQuestions) {

                let temp = ask(msg, text)
                //ISSUE THERE
                text = temp.text
                replyMarkup = temp.replyMarkup
                
                } else {
                    //rest of code
                    }
                }

                //rest of code
            } else {
                return msg.reply.text('⛔️ You can't throw dice right now.');
            }
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return DisplayError(msg.chat.id, 'Main:', err)
    }
}
```

Function `ask(msg, txt)` returns `{ text: txt, replyMarkup: replyMarkup }` .

I can output the object as text in console in the `ask` function, but can't output it in the `throwDice` function.

What am i doing wrong?

(Sorry, but i need to put some text so Stackoverflow can post this question)

Comment: because this is an async function...?

Comment: You have a syntax error in that code.

Answer (score 0):

The function is asynchronous, but it doesn't have `await`, so the code doesn't work. I do not know why Visual Studio 22 didn't show a syntax error. Thanks for answers, but i figured it out earlier.